# How to compare no-case sensitive strings IDC

Tags: ida, debugging, winapi

So I want to track when a certain file is loaded into an Win32 app. That's way I put a break-point on 'CreateFile' which compares the first parameter with the target file name, but the problem is that it is a case-sensitive comparison. How to do it non-sensitive?

Here is the break-point condition on 'CreateFileA':

```
GetString(DbgDword(esp + 0x4), -1, ASCSTR_C)  == "D:\\3K-MILLENNIUM\\3K-MILLENNIUM\\USER_LAW.TXT"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of IDA are you using? Versions 6.6+ allow you to enter breakpoint conditions in Python - http://i.imgur.com/4Z2xwfP.gif

Comment: I was with 6.5 but just got one 6.6. So can you tell me how would the script looks like then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this comparsion using IDA-Python 1.7.0 and IDA Demo 6.6. The script code is this:

```
Tmp = GetString(DbgDword(cpu.ESP + 0x4), -1, ASCSTR_C)

return str(Tmp).upper() == "D:\\3K-MILLENNIUM\\3K-MILLENNIUM\\USER_LAW.TXT"
```

Link to [IDA-Python 1.7.0](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EFFB2D14F5621F5F%216706), compiled for Win32 (32bit & 64bit).

Answer (score 2):

In the breakpoint settings for the given breakpoint, press the <kbd>...</kbd> button, select Python as the scripting langauge, and use the following script body:

```
GetString(DbgDword(esp + 0x4), -1, ASCSTR_C).upper()  == "D:\\3K-MILLENNIUM\\3K-MILLENNIUM\\USER_LAW.TXT"
```

[image: Conditional breakpoint]

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't work. It says that <string> has no attribute 'upper'.

Comment: Odd, that error doesn't repro for me. Can you try the following? `string.upper(GetString(DbgDword(esp + 0x4), -1, ASCSTR_C)) == "D:\\3K-MILLENNIUM\\3K-MILLENNIUM\\USER_LAW.TXT"`

Comment: It just doesn't work, at all. Can I talk with you?

Comment: OK - I was able to get my hands on IDAPython 1.7.0. But now it doesn't work either. Any suggestions?